# React command on yarn start and also init server with same command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, command, yarnpkg, react-scripts

I'm trying to attach another command to `yarn start`. I'm not sure if it is possible but when I run command `yarn start` I want my react app to start and I also want to fire up my server at the same time.

What I do know is use 2 terminals one with react app directory and call on `yarn start`

```
C:\Users\ivanr\Documents\GitHub\bees\business-scheduler>
```

and one with server directory (which is inside react app directory) and call on `node src/index.js`

```
C:\Users\ivanr\Documents\GitHub\bees\business-scheduler\server>
```

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start", // is it possible that I can say in server directory run node src/index.js here?
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently)

First install it

```
$ npm install concurrently
```

Then use it in your command

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently \"yarn start-client\" \"yarn start-server\"",
  "start-client": "react-scripts start",
  "start-server": "cd .\server && node src/index.js"
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly the kind of structure I was looking for but didn't find

Answer (score 0):

You can use [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all)

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "lint":  "eslint src",
    "build": "babel src -o lib"
}
```

npm-run-all clean lint build